# Play 2.4 with Ebean NullPointerException

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have been struggling for years with the Play! Framework, with the constant shift in direction and major API changes, it is a constant moving target.

I have had the recent unfortunate task of updating a Play 2.1 or 2.2 project that was NOT compatible with Java 8, to a Play 2.4 that is compatible with Java 8.

**EDIT**: Heroku is not dropping support for Java 7.

Now I'm dealing with a NullPointerException INSIDE the Ebean class and I'm not sure why. I have the following code:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    public static Model.Finder<Long, User> find() {
        return new Model.Finder<Long, User>(User.class);
    } 

    public static boolean emailExists(String email) {
        if(User.find().where().eq("email",email).findRowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException when running the:

```
User.find().where().eq("email",email).findRowCount() > 0
```

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.query(Model.java:548)
at com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.where(Model.java:742)
at models.User.emailExists(User.java:9)
at controllers.UserController.doLogin(UserController.java:208)
```

The code runs fine in development, but crashes when pushing to Heroku, why would this be??

As you can see, the null pointer happens inside the com.avaje.ebean.Model$Find.query() method. I have review the code within Ebean to try and determine what could be causing this with now clue. I have also turned on Ebean debugging to the max level of 9, and ebean appears to identify all of the entities appropriately.

I was using:

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

but upgraded to:

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")

which did not help resolve the issue....

Any guidance into this would be so helpful! I am over the Play! Framework at this point and will no longer use it for ANY projects.....

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is not deleting servers with Java 7. I assume you are referring to the [cedar-14 migration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration), which does change the **default** JDK to 8. But you can still use Java 7 by adding a `system.properties` file to the root directory of your application with these contents:

```
java.runtime.version=1.7
```

Add that file to Git as well.

Comment: Thank you for this information, while this does solve the issue of deploying still not sure why Ebean does not deploy on Heroku when it's functioning in the dev environment.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how the Database is configured in your app. if you open a ticket at http://help.heroku.com we can take a closer look

Comment: I'll go ahead and submit a ticket to try and figure this out, thanks!